# Compilation error on file web/controllers/auth_controller.ex undefined function plug/1

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ueberauth

### The Cryptic Error Message

While attempting to implement `ueberauth` for our project, we cam across a error message we had not seen before. (*note this is not specific to `ueberauth` this error will be seen in any controller that fails to include the controller "helpers"*)

The exact error message is:

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/auth_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/auth_controller.ex:4: undefined function plug/1
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Code Snapshot: https://github.com/dwyl/auth/pull/9/commits/e2550c558832ff9c4a442b570224a1ccacbfdb02

### Answer:

Forgot to include `:controller` helpers in our controller file ...

```
use Auth.Web, :controller
```

Thanks to Sam Houston for taking a look at the code and spotting how to fix it.
https://github.com/dwyl/auth/pull/9/commits/823f7d79561f733a9d131b26a3f6a4d74da59842

Posting this question + answer in `case` someone `else` sees this error message in their Phoenix project and does not find an answer when googling.

Comment: Post answer as an answer ⇓ please :)

Answer (score 1):

The `plug` macro is defined in Plug.Builder and you could import it before usage with:

```
use Plug.Builder

plug :any_plug_you_like
```

in case of Phoenix it defined in `Phoenix.Controller.Pipeline` which injected in `Phoenix.Controller` which again injected via `use Auth.Web, :controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the answer for others to interpret it.

```
use Auth.Web, :controller
```